# Do While Loop skipping condition

Tags: java

I'm working on some code which takes the user input and loops using a while statement when the input is not what the program is looking for.
For some reason, the while statement is always executing even when the conditions are not met.
I've tried fixing the conditions, but I'm not sure whats going on.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a height within 0 and 23");
    height = s.nextInt();
} while (height < 0 || height > 23);{
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer within 0 and 23");
    height = s.nextInt();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code would be invalid if the semicolon were removed -- the `while` goes with the preceding `do` loop, not with the following block.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, the second set of braces are extraneous to this code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a standard while loop would suit you better

```
int height = 0;
while (True) {
    System.out.println("Enter a height within 0 and 23");
    height = s.nextInt();
    if (height < 0 || height > 23) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer within 0 and 23");
        continue;
    } else break;
}
```

Basically, this "code-block" is not applied to the while statement of a do-while

```
{
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer within 0 and 23");
    height = s.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Ah, that helps I'll go with this thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have too much code.  All you need is:

```
do {
  System.out.println("Enter a height within 0 and 23");
  height = s.nextInt();
} while (height < 0 || height > 23);
```

A `do ... while` loop has the `while` at the end, not the start.

Comment: I think you missed the "Please enter" prompt

Comment: This answer is correct but perhaps could add more explanation as to why. The do while loop executes the code in between the first { } pair at least once, and more times if the condition is true, which is evaluated after the code block has executed. The second code block after the while is therefore just in a code block of its own, nothing to do with any looping, and is therefore unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you have a do loop AND a while loop mixed together. get rid of the "do {" and the 1st "}". Also do what shmosel said and remove the ";". This will allow you to get the first int outside the while loop, then if it is within your condition, it will start looping.

```
  System.out.println("Enter a height within 0 and 23");
  height = s.nextInt();
  // now have 1st condition for the whie loop
  while (height < 0 || height > 23) {
     System.out.println("Please enter an integer within 0 and 23");
     height = s.nextInt();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the question , the while statement is always executing even when the conditions are not met.However this is not true.

The while loop is not getting executed for inputs when height is in between 0 and 23 (inclusive)
inputs : 0 <= height <= 23.